# Can't use/find my custom view when defining layout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-linearlayout, android-xml

I'm trying to create a custom view and then using that custom view in my layout.

My custom view is called `NodePickup` and I have two files for that:

- res/layout/nodepickup.xml
- src/com.codeshogun.android.swipesample/NodePickup.java

nodepickup.xml:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/LinearLayout01"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="48dip"
    android:background="#aa0000"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/ImageView01"
        android:layout_width="48dip"
        android:layout_height="48dip"
        android:background="#FFFFFF"
        android:src="@drawable/arrow_up_green" >
    </ImageView>

    <LinearLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/LinearLayout01"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:background="#FFFFFF"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/time"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="14:46 (15 min), 1 res"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:textSize="12dip" >
        </TextView>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/road"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Karl XII gatan 6"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:textSize="12dip" >
        </TextView>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/name"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Bertil Håkansson"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:textSize="12dip" >
        </TextView>
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

NodePickup.java:

```
package com.codeshogun.android.swipesample.CustomViews;

import com.codeshogun.android.swipesample.R;
import android.content.Context;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;

public class NodePickup extends LinearLayout {
    public NodePickup(Context context, AttributeSet attributeSet) {
        super(context, attributeSet);
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        inflater.inflate(R.layout.nodepickup, this);
    }
}
```

I am trying to add this view/widget to a layout file, main.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ViewFlipper 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/com.codeshogun.android.swipesample.CustomViews"
    android:id="@+id/flipper"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent">
        <TextView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:background="#FF0000" />

        <!-- If I try to add it here, it wont work -->
        <com.   <!-- <-- will not give me the widget...? -->

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent">
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:background="#00FF00" />
    </LinearLayout>
</ViewFlipper>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: the "some.path.to.package" I mentioned above is really what is in the files: com.codeshogun.android.swipesample

Just a pointer, dunno what I didnt write it out in the first place...

Comment: Why do you have the same id for LinearLayout? Is that causing a conflict?

Comment: Have a look at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1957252/connection-between-view-in-the-xml-file-and-extened-view-class

Comment: Dave Webb: thx, but I dont see how that link helps =(
aforloney: i will check that today.

But in general: i should be able to add the View as I described above, by adding that tag in the XML? and the custom View should be "suggested" when I write it, right?

Comment: I think i got some stuff to work now. the andrid:layout_width and android:layout_height is apparently required, but I dont get them as suggestions when I start typing "android:la...".
Usually, Eclipse suggests what options where are, but I only get 4 suggestions ("default namespace", "noshemaloc" etc).
Any ideas?